# I need help on accessing address book in Flash Builder 4.6 - Win 7

Tags: iphone, ios, flash-builder, flashdevelop

Hey guys so I am trying to dev a app for IPhone and am very very stumped right now.  I have tried using Contact Editor - ANE (http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/contact-editor/#comment-7488) but I get an error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor::ContactEditor could not be found.

    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at ADLAppEntry/run()
    at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

I made sure I included the correct file path under the ActionScript Build Path, besides that I don't know what else I can do.  I do get the function like ContactsSimpe() function that hints when looking for a function.  So I know it is connecting but once I go to compile and test in the flash pro I get this error.  Here is some code that may help:

```
   code....
    import pl.mllr.extensions.contactEditor.ContactEditor;

        public class soscode extends MovieClip   {
            var contactEditor:ContactEditor;


            public function soscode() {
                stop();
                init();
                contactEditor.getContacts();


            }
     code...
```

in my project window on left the .swc file for the native extension is in the reference folder.  That is about it.

I really need some help on this an if you could give me a hand I would much appreciate it!

David,

Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this might be a bit late now, but I've just been having this problem myself, and it was caused by the ANE not being packaged with the app when it's sent to the device / simulator.

Classes within the NE weren't being found at runtime, but were accessible in Flash Builder.

It turned out that by default the .ANE file wasn't copied to the device.

To fix this, change the following project property:

*ActionScript Build Packaging -> Apple iOS -> Native Extensions -> **Check 'Package' for the ANE***

No idea why it wasn't included by default. When you uncheck 'Package' you get a warning telling you that it may cause runtime issues!

Hope this is of use for somebody.